# Basic rollup tutorial with config option isn't working for me. I'm getting  You must specify an --input (-i) option

Tags: rollupjs

I am following the basic tutorial on https://rollupjs.org/. In the root of my folder, I have a package.json:

```
{
  "name": "rollup-tutorial",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "devDependencies": {
    "rollup": "^0.50.0"
  }
}
```

And rollup.config.js:

```
export default {
    input: 'src/main.js',
    output: {
      file: 'bundle.js',
      format: 'cjs'
    }
 };
```

src/main.js:

```
import foo from './foo.js';
export default function () {
  console.log(foo);
}
```

And src/foo.js

```
export default 'hello world!';
```

If I run `rollup -c` I get:

`You must specify an --input (-i) option`.

But if I run the previous example on the tutorial, without using the config file, it works fine. The command is `rollup src/main.js -o bundle.js -f cjs`.

One strange thing is that the package.json file says that the version is `0.50.0` but if I call rollup -v then I get `rollup version 0.41.4`. I'm not sure how to update to version `0.50.0` but I tried npm install and npm update.

Any help getting the tutorial to work? Thanks!

Comment: Do you have a global installed rollup? Try ./node_modules/.bin/rollup -v

Comment: That gave me the right version number `rollup version 0.50.0`. Okay I replaced rollup with `./node_modules/.bin/rollup` and it works. Feel free to write an answer and I'll accept it! Thanks!

Comment: A good way to ensure you're using the locally installed version (rather than an out-of-date globally installed one) is to add a `scripts` entry to package.json, so that you can do (for example) `npm run build`. Or, if you're using a recent version of node/npm you can do `npx rollup -c` instead of `rollup -c`